# Webpack config output file giving 404

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Webpack Config:-

```
var config = {
   entry: './main.js',

   output: {
      path:'./',
      filename: 'index.js',
   },

   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 8080
   },

   module: {
      loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',

            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}

module.exports = config;
```

App.jsx:-

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            Hello World!!!
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default App;
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">

   <head>
      <meta charset = "UTF-8">
      <title>React App</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div id = "app"></div>
      <script src = "index.js"></script>
   </body>

</html>
```

main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "reacttest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test app",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
  "author": "snehasis",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
}
```

I am starting the server using npm start command as I have added the start script in package.json. I expect to see "Hello World!!!" on the browser at localhost:8080. But I am getting a 404 on index.html on script include index.js.

Any ideas?

Comment: The index.html is in your root directory? (`./`)

Comment: Yes, all files are in the same root directory

Comment: Maybe it would be simpler to hook up html-webpack-plugin. It can generate correct references for you and so on.